# Changing cursor inside Rectangle c#

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes, mousemove, mouse-position

When I draw a line on a `Canvas` by dragging the `Mouse`, I have to add `Lines` to the `Canvas`'s children rather than add the current position of the `Mouse` - I guess that this is caused since the `Mouse`'s movement is faster than `Rendering` of the `Canvas`.

I created a new `BoundingBox` class which inherits from `Shape` and implements the `DefiningGeometry` property. This new `Shape` consists of a `Rectangle` and a `Text`:

**IShapeBase:**

```
public abstract class IShapeBase : Shape
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public bool ShapeReady { get; set; }
    public Point Location { get; set; }
    public Brush Color { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool OnResizing { get; set; }
    public bool OnMoving { get; set; }

    protected IShapeBase() { ShapeReady = false; }
    public abstract bool IsInBounds(Point currentLocation);
}
```

**BoudingBox:**

```
public class BoundingBox : IShapeBase
{
    private enum ResizeDirection { None, Top, Left, Bottom, Right, TopLeft, TopRight, BottomRight, BottomLeft }

    private PathGeometry m_pathGeometry;
    private RectangleGeometry m_rectangleGeometry;
    private Geometry m_textGeometry;
    private Point m_downClick = new Point(-1, -1);
    private Point m_previousLocation = new Point(-1, -1);
    private Rect m_rectangle;
    private ResizeDirection m_resizeDirection = ResizeDirection.None;

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            var formattedText = new FormattedText(Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("Times New-Roman"), 14, Brushes.Transparent);
            var chosenTextPoint = new Point
            {
                X = ((Location.X < BottomRight.X) ? Location.X : BottomRight.X) + 5,
                Y = ((Location.Y < BottomRight.Y) ? Location.Y : BottomRight.Y) + 5
            };

            Stroke = Color;
            StrokeThickness = IsMouseDirectlyOver ? 1.5 : 1;

            m_rectangle = new Rect(Location, BottomRight);
            m_pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
            m_rectangleGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(m_rectangle);
            m_textGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(chosenTextPoint);

            m_pathGeometry.AddGeometry(m_rectangleGeometry);
            m_pathGeometry.AddGeometry(m_textGeometry);

            Fill = Brushes.Transparent;

            return m_pathGeometry;
        }
    }
    public Point BottomRight { get; set; }
    public Rect Rectangle { get { return m_rectangle; } }

    private void CheckHowToResize(Point currentLocation)
    {
        var currentTopLeft = m_rectangle.TopLeft;
        var currentBottomRight = m_rectangle.BottomRight;

        if (m_resizeDirection != ResizeDirection.None) return;

        if ((currentLocation.X >= currentTopLeft.X - 5) && (currentLocation.X <= currentTopLeft.X + 5))
            m_resizeDirection = ((currentLocation.Y >= currentBottomRight.Y - 5) && (currentLocation.Y <= currentBottomRight.Y + 5)) ? ResizeDirection.BottomLeft : ResizeDirection.Left;

        if ((currentLocation.Y >= currentTopLeft.Y - 5) && (currentLocation.Y <= currentTopLeft.Y + 5))
            m_resizeDirection = (m_resizeDirection == ResizeDirection.Left) ? ResizeDirection.TopLeft : ResizeDirection.Top;

        if ((currentLocation.X >= currentBottomRight.X - 5) && (currentLocation.X <= currentBottomRight.X + 5))
            m_resizeDirection = (m_resizeDirection == ResizeDirection.Top) ? ResizeDirection.TopRight : ResizeDirection.Right;

        if ((currentLocation.Y >= currentBottomRight.Y - 5) && (currentLocation.Y <= currentBottomRight.Y + 5) && (m_resizeDirection != ResizeDirection.BottomLeft))
            m_resizeDirection = (m_resizeDirection == ResizeDirection.Right) ? ResizeDirection.BottomRight : ResizeDirection.Bottom;

        if (m_resizeDirection != ResizeDirection.None)
            OnResizing = true;
    }
    private void Resize(Point currentLocation)
    {
        switch (m_resizeDirection)
        {
                case ResizeDirection.Left:
                {
                    Location = new TranslateTransform(currentLocation.X - Location.X, 0).Transform(Location);
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
                    break;
                }
                case ResizeDirection.Top:
                {
                    Location = new TranslateTransform(0, currentLocation.Y - Location.Y).Transform(Location);
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
                    break;
                }
                case ResizeDirection.TopLeft:
                {
                    Location = new TranslateTransform(currentLocation.X - Location.X, currentLocation.Y - Location.Y).Transform(Location);
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
                    break;
                }
                case ResizeDirection.Right:
                {
                    BottomRight = new TranslateTransform(currentLocation.X - BottomRight.X, 0).Transform(BottomRight);
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
                    break;
                }
                case ResizeDirection.Bottom:
                {
                    BottomRight = new TranslateTransform(0, currentLocation.Y - BottomRight.Y).Transform(BottomRight);
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
                    break;
                }
                case ResizeDirection.BottomRight:
                {
                    BottomRight = new TranslateTransform(currentLocation.X - BottomRight.X, currentLocation.Y - BottomRight.Y).Transform(BottomRight);
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
                    break;
                }
                case ResizeDirection.TopRight:
                {
                    Location = new TranslateTransform(0, currentLocation.Y - Location.Y).Transform(Location);
                    BottomRight = new TranslateTransform(currentLocation.X - BottomRight.X, 0).Transform(BottomRight);
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.SizeNESW;
                    break;
                }
                case ResizeDirection.BottomLeft:
                {
                    Location = new TranslateTransform(currentLocation.X - Location.X, 0).Transform(Location);
                    BottomRight = new TranslateTransform(0, currentLocation.Y - BottomRight.Y).Transform(BottomRight);
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.SizeNESW;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    public override bool IsInBounds(Point currentLocation)
    {
        return ((currentLocation.X >= m_rectangle.Left - 2) && (currentLocation.X <= m_rectangle.Right + 2) &&
                (currentLocation.Y >= m_rectangle.Top - 2) && (currentLocation.Y <= m_rectangle.Bottom + 2));
    }


    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Mouse.Capture(this);
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            m_downClick = e.GetPosition(this);
    }                  
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return;

        Thread.Sleep(20);
        var currentLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

        if (!OnMoving)
        {
            CheckHowToResize(currentLocation);
            if (OnResizing)
            {
                Resize(currentLocation);
                return;
            }
        }

        m_pathGeometry.Transform = new TranslateTransform((currentLocation.X - m_downClick.X), (currentLocation.Y - m_downClick.Y));
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.ScrollAll;
        OnMoving = true;

        m_previousLocation = currentLocation;
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        m_downClick = new Point(-1, -1);
        ReleaseMouseCapture();
        OnResizing = false;
        OnMoving = false;
        m_resizeDirection = ResizeDirection.None;
        Location = m_pathGeometry.Transform.Transform(Location);
        BottomRight = m_pathGeometry.Transform.Transform(BottomRight);
    }
    protected override void OnIsMouseDirectlyOverChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        StrokeThickness = IsMouseDirectlyOver ? 1.5 : 1;
    }
}
```

I would like to make sure that the `BoudningBox` will be able to move only in the boundaries of the `Canvas` on which it is being drawn.

Currently, since I'm using `ClipCursor` from outside, I'm able to limit the creation and resizing of the `Shape` to the `Canvas`'s boundaries, but if I try to move it by clicking the center of the `Shape` and dragging it, then I can move it until the mouse hits the `Canvas`'s boundaries, but the `Shape` is half on the `Canvas` and half outside.

My main difficulty is detecting the exactly when does the `Mouse` hit either the `Shape` or the `Canvas`'s boundaries because (again, I guess) the `rendering` is slower than the movement of the `Mouse`.

This affects everything I'm trying to implement:

1) Highlighting the `BoundingBox` when the mouse is on it.

2) Changing the `Mouse`'s cursor to scroll/resize/arrow depending on what's underneath the current location of the `Mouse`.

3) Move the `BoundinBox` within the boundaries of its `parent`Canvas`.

Can such accuracy be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

- Define a border-rectangle for the Canvas (container)
- Get the four bounding-box (child's) corner points
- Before moving the bounding box, check if the corners will lie in the container
- You can use `translateTransform.Transform(point)` before moving
- You can use Rect's `Contains` method to check if point lies within
- Apply transform only if all 4 corners are within

Comment: I tried all of what you wrote with the `Canvas` axis system (check between 0 and `CanvasWidth` for the `X` coordinates and between 0 and `CanvasHeight` for the `Y` coordinates). That didn't work much, the movement wasn't smooth. Do you think that Adding a border-rectangle will behave different?

Comment: See if using RenderTransform helps.